# Use URL returned by JavaScript function in XHTML

Tags: javascript, xhtml

So I have a JavaScript function:

```
function loadHelp() {
    window.location = "http://www.examplewebsite.com";
    return false;
}
```

No, when I click on:
`<a target="_blank" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadHelp()" class="btn-image help">&#32;</a>`
Nothing happens.

I have also tried:

```
function loadHelp() {
    return http://www.somewebsite.com
}
```

and

```
<a target="_blank" href="loadHelp()" class="btn-image help">&#32;</a>
```

but that doesn't work either.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<a target="_blank" href="javascript:loadHelp();" class="btn-image help">&#32;</a>
```

---

Also the one you have already works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/SW7bZ/

Comment: I had tried that too, that simply appends loadHelp() to the current directory's URL. For example if I am at `www.somewebsite/somedirectory/someotheridrectory/code.seam`, clicking on that button opens the URL `www.somewebsite/somedirectory/someotheridrectory/loadHelp()`, which does not exist.

Comment: @mahendru. you did not try that. use `javascript:loadHelp()`

Comment: I just tested it again, it does exactly what I said it does in my comment.

Comment: @mahendru, please post your code to http://jsfiddle.net so I can see exactly what you are doing

Comment: My bad, I did indeed keep on testing my old code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the full path (with protocol) i.e:

```
function loadHelp() {
  window.location = "http://www.examplewebsite.com";
}
```

Otherwise, it's treated as a relative path.

Comment: I do have the full path, I just typed that up for a quick example. I'll edit it in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your `function loadHelp()` simply needs to be defined earlier.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: loadHelp is not defined

was probably your error. Check your console.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure you have everything in the proper place, like the script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>How to make a javascript link</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadHelp()
            {
                window.location = "www.examplewebsite.com";
                return false;
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <a target="_blank" href="javascript: loadHelp();" class="btn-image help">Test &#32;</a>
    </body>
</html>
```